# If a Subgroup has Finite Index in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ , Does it have Finite Index in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I was struggling with that last line of this proof. (this was found here: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~felix077/download/sec3.pdf)

[image]

I understand that ker$(\varphi \sigma) =\varphi^{-1} (\sigma^{-1} (N)) $, and that this is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't understand how they can talk about its index in  $\mathbb{Q}$.

The earlier problem said there are no proper subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a finite index, but aren't we dealing with $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ here? If a subgroup has finite index in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ , does it have finite index in  $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I think you mean $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ , not $\Bbb Q\backslash\Bbb  Z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. This is a quotient group.

Now, since $N\leq \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite index then the quotient $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})/N$ is a finite group. $\varphi\circ\sigma:\mathbb{Q}\to(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})/N$ is a homomorphism of groups. Hence by the first isomorphism theorem we have $\mathbb{Q}/Ker(\varphi\circ\sigma)\cong Im(\varphi\circ\sigma)\leq(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})/N$. It follows that $\mathbb{Q}/Ker(\varphi\circ\sigma)$ is a finite group, so $Ker(\varphi\circ\sigma)$ has finite index in $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, why is it a proper subgroup? Because if the kernel would be all $\mathbb{Q}$ then we would get that the kernel of $\varphi$ (which is $N$) is all $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is a contradiction to $N$ being a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I thought $N$ was a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ because it is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ , which is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$. So $N$ doesn't have to be a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ because even if it is all of  $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ , it is still a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Also, why does $N$ having a finite index imply that the quotient $(\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}) /N$ is finite? The problem didn't seem to assume that $N$ was finite. . .

Comment: I think you are confused with the definitions. If $G$ is any group, $H$ a subgroup then the index $[G:H]$ is the number of left (or right, it is the same number) cosets of $H$, i.e it is the cardinality of the set $G/H=\{gH: g\in G\}$. Now, if $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$ then $G/N$ also forms a group with respect to the operation $(g_1N)(g_2N)=g_1g_2N$. This is called a quotient group. It is not a subgroup of $G$, not at all! Now, $G/N$ as a set is still the set of left cosets, so here the index $[G:N]$ is exactly the size of the quotient group.

Comment: Now, in the exercise we work with $\mathbb{Q}$. Since this is an abelian group any subgroup is normal in it, so we can always define a quotient group. $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is also abelian (as a quotient group of an abelian group), hence all its subgroups are normal. So when we take a subgroup $N\leq \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ with finite index this implies that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, and the quotient $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})/N$ is a finite group. This doesn't mean $N$ itself is finite.